# Can we say Shall he/she attend?

Tags: questions, will-shall

Can we say

> Shall he/she attend?

Is it possible to make a question with **shall**?

Comment: In *statements*, using (somewhat dated/formal/literary) ***shall*** instead of the more common ***will*** usually conveys emphasis (thus *You **shall** go to the ball* is more emphatic that *You will go to the ball*. In *questions*, we usually use ***will*** for a simple enquiry *(Will we go out tonight?)*, where ***Shall** we go out tonight?* is more of a *suggestion* (often, regarding some suggested course of action the speaker is in favour of adopting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that today it is more common to use **will** to make a question about the future. (Parrott's book cited below states this).

**Shall he /she attend?** is ok but **Will he attend?** is more common.

**EDIT** We can use shall with other pronouns  and names and with other appropriate verbs. Some more examples are shown below:

Shall I/she/he/we/they/It/John/ attend/go/come/arrive?

Shall ,a  modal auxiliary verb, is more commonly used in the following ways:

**1. To offer your help**.

e.g. Shall I open the door for you?

**2.When making a suggestion.**

e.g. Shall we go out for lunch together?

3.**Asking for instructions**

e.g. What shall we do now?

Source: Practical English usage by Michael Swan & Grammar for English Language Teachers. By Martin Parrott.

Comment: So can i use Shall she attend? If you answer this, It'd be great. Thanks again!..

Comment: Yes, you can say Shall he attend (as I said above) but it is less common to ask it this way. The use of Will is more commonly used.

Comment: I just didn't get Can i use shall with all pronouns and verbs. As i mean Shall he/she/it/they/you + verb?

Comment: You can use it with subject pronouns like  I he ,she we, they etc or with names.  It also works with most verbs.  However, although it is technically correct I would personally use Will  which is more modern usage and sounds less formal in my opinion.

Comment: Nice!, Can you add this into your answer? It'd be great.

Comment: See under EDIT. Please remember this structure is not commonly used and can sound strange to the modern ear.

Answer (score 2):

*Shall he attend?* to me sounds very old-fashioned and formal, and means something like "Is it your intention that he should attend?" It's not just about a future event, but about somebody's intention for the future.

On the other hand, *Shall I attend?* is perfectly normal to me, but it is asking for permission or guidance, not for a prediction.

**Edit:** Some English dialects don't use *shall* at all; some (like mine, from England) use *shall* freely for first person subjects ("I" and "we"). For other persons, it is rare, and usually carries a sense of command or permission.

Comment: 'Should he attend?' is the 3rd-person equivalent of the guidance-seeking sense.

Comment: So can't i use? My friends who lives in USA told me that it's possible.

Comment: So I wanna use that for He/She/They/You for making questions.

Comment: Shall I open the window? Shall I leave now? It is used when you ask someone if he or she wants you to do something for him or her. Or suggestions as stated by FF above.  I would not say asking permission necessarily. Shall I attend? for example, could be offering to attend in place of someone else. Shall is also used to emphasize something:  You shall go at once. (mostly BrE but also AmE educated speech).

Comment: Can someone answer my question?

Comment: @Odin, it seems to me that both I and user242899 have answered your question, in slightly different ways. What more are you looking for?

Comment: I just didn't get Can i use shall with all pronouns and verbs. As i mean Shall he/she/it/they/you + verb?

Comment: No. Some English dialects make little use of _shall_ at all. Others (like my own) freely use _shall_ with _I_ or _we_. But _shall_ with other persons is rare, and and always has a connotation of intention or command.

Comment: What do you mean? Can't we say Shall he/she/it/you/they go?

Comment: @Odin, user242899 said "Shall he /she attend? is ok but Will he attend? is more common.", and I said 'Shall he attend? to me sounds very old-fashioned and formal, and means something like "Is it your intention that he should attend?"' What more do you want?

Comment: I just wanna know Shall + All pronouns + A verb is possible?

Comment: Yes, @Odin, Shall can be used with any subject and any verb. But except for first person pronouns, it is rare, and is always about command or permission.

Comment: Can you add this into your answer? please.